# ios- creating views programmatically clutters viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

In ios project, if we build all the UI programmatically in viewDidLoad method, the view controller becomes so heavy. What is the best practice to keep the UI code separate without using interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

When we have a function that does too much, we break its process up into steps and put the steps in separate functions.  Then the original function's job changes to calling the helper functions properly.  So you could create other methods and have `viewDidLoad` call them.

When we have an object that does too much, we break its job up into sub-jobs and make other objects responsible for those sub-jobs.  Then the original object's job changes to calling the helper objects properly.  So you could create `UIView` subclasses that know how to create and arrange their children, and make `viewDidLoad` just instantiate the top-level view.

But there is no best practice to keep the UI code separate without using IB.  The best practice is to use IB.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of configuration code for UI elements you could (should) create category methods and move that stuff out of the view controller.  In general, categories are your friends when trying to keep view controllers lighter.  Like was mentioned before, though, the best practice really is to use Interface Builder.